Custom datum transformation pyproj from unknown CRS to WGS84
I have a set of location points that represents real points on earth in Easting and Northing, but these records have lost their information of their original datum, e.g. :



Point
Original X
Original Y
Datum




Point A
100
200
Unknown


Point B
200
300
Unknown



Let's say that I make a new measurement of those points with modern GPS and retrieve another set of coordinates.
After new measurement I have these records:
Point | new X | new Y | Datum |
------|-----|------------|-------|
Point A|105        |  205       | Unknown|
Point B|205        | 305        | Unknown|
Can I make a transformation from the previously unknown original datum to WGS84 (preferrably using pyproj)?

You'll need at least 3 tie points for an affine transformation to get scale and rotation.

ok let's say I have 3 points now, how can I do that?

Read Here. You can use the resulting WKT in PyProj.
